# Is it possible to specify time out value on an Execute SQL Task?

Tags: ssis

I have a Stored Procedure which was scheduled as a job. A Timeout expired issue occurs when the job scheduled is executed. I am going to implement this Stored Procedure to SSIS Package by calling the Stored Procedure in a Execute SQL Task or apply Stored Procedure script into a Script Task. What should I do/apply for avoiding Time Out Expiry issue in the Package? Is there property related to time out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a `TimeOut` property on the Execute SQL Task. It is right in the first section named General. Refer the screenshot **#1**. Ideally, you should work on fine tuning the stored procedure.

[**Microsoft TechNet**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188957.aspx) documentation states the following definition for the *TimeOut* property:

```
Specify the maximum number of seconds the task will run before timing out. 
A value of 0 indicates an infinite time. The default is 0.

Note: Stored procedures do not time out if they emulate sleep functionality by 
providing time for connections to be made and transactions to complete that is 
greater than the number of seconds specified by TimeOut. However, stored 
procedures that execute queries are always subject to the time restriction 
specified by TimeOut.
```

Hope that helps.

**Screenshots:**

**#1:** Execute SQL Task TimeOut Property

[image: Execute SQL Task TimeOut Property]

Answer (score 0):

was getting this `0xC020801c` when running the SSIS job as SQL server agent pulling data from Oracle db into sql server db. Setting the timeout to 300 seconds did the trick. Also had to set the `Run64bit = false` but did not have to click run 32-bit under advance options on SQL Server job (after setting up the step to run integration service package in connection manager -> advance) .